# Icon size inside an application is too large

Tags: icons, gtk

Whenever I uses a software that uses gtk as Its source for its viewscreen, the icons on buttoms and some are about the twice the size of icon on my unity launcher

I'm using a Ununtu 15.04 with beforementioned Unity

please help

Comment: Please edit your question with more details, like a screenshot and the resolution of your screen.